# Errors shown while installing apps, but the apps still works

Tags: gnome-terminal, dpkg

I started to notice the error below when I install apps from the terminal with *sudo apt-get install* the apps work but the error still remains I don't know if its due the dpkg or ubuntu-software-center: `/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/libGLEW.so.1.5 is not a symbolic link`

`ls -l /usr/lib32/libGLEW.so.1.5` returns

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 225068 2012-01-29 22:10 /usr/lib32/libGLEW.so.1.5
```

`file /usr/lib32/libGLEW.so.1.5` returns

```
/usr/lib32/libGLEW.so.1.5: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped.
```

How do I solve this, should I worry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application is working, then it is a "warning". Hard to know the cause of the warning, my guess would be within the application itself or packaging in that the binary is looking for '/usr/lib32/libGLEW.so.1.5' to be a symbolic link. The lib is either not a symbolic link or the function is provided by an alternate lib.

Does either of the following commands give you a clue ?

```
ls -l /usr/lib32/libGLEW.so.1.5
file /usr/lib32/libGLEW.so.1.5
```

If the application is working, without problems, probably not worth spending too much time worrying about it.